# Which Stack Exchange site is the best place to ask about iPhone's YouTube app?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, iphone

I am trying to understand why the YouTube app asks for the video in multiple HTTP requests.

Comment: Oh, great job, @PopularDemand. We submitted at the exact same second. Revision history has me overwriting your edit, but the display has you overwriting mine!

Answer (score 4):

http://apple.stackexchange.com